# Java, How to save node coordinates to list

Tags: java, shortest-path

I am creating the shortest route program for a project. Currently, I have data being read from a .cav file. The program tells me how many caves (nodes) there is in the file and also gives me the coordinates for each node.

**Code**:

```
//Get coordinates

for (int count = 1; count < ((noOfCaves*2)+1); count=count+2){
    System.out.println("Cave at " + data[count] +"," +data[count+1]);
}
```

**Output**:

```
Cave at 2,8
Cave at 3,2
Cave at 14,5
Cave at 7,6
Cave at 11,2
Cave at 11,6
Cave at 14,1
```

How do I now store these locations as x,y into a list?
Thanks :)

Comment: I meant to add that I cannot manually enter the coordinates into a list as the .cav file can change and different coordinates would be generated automatically. I need to list to auto save the coords that can be taken from any .cav file.

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of your objects

```
public class Cave{
  private int x;
  private int y
  Cave(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
 public int getX(){
  return x;
 }
 public int getY(){
  return y;
 }
}
```

then in your main create a list of elements:

```
List<Cave> caves = new ArrayList<>();
Cave c1 = new Cave(2,8);
caves.add(c1);
```

after populating a list, simply use for each

```
caves.forEach(cave -> {
  System.out.println("this cave is in x:" + cave.getX() 
  + " and y:" + cave.getY());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You create a list and add the coordinates! In this case, I would a string list:

```
List<String> coords = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int count = 1; count < ((noOfCaves * 2) + 1); count = count + 2){
    System.out.println("Cave at " + data[count] +"," + data[count + 1]);
    coords.add(String.valueOf(data[count]) + "," + String.valueOf(data[count + 1]));
}
```

You  can  use `String.split(",")` and `Integer#parseInt(String)` to get the X and Y separately.

Comment: Java is OO language, and this answer is totally wrong according to OO standards...

Comment: I am providing an approach that only uses classes included in the JDK. While it  is  true that Java is object-oriented, there are some cases where creating a new data type is not necessary. For example, if these coordinates are only used in this method, it would be a complete waste of time to create a custom data type only to be used once.

Comment: whole oo approach is designed in the way to be maintainable, you are suggesting to write code that is not readable nor maintainable. In your code only you and god knows what is happening, and after few weeks only god will know...

Comment: Thanks, I think thats exactly what i needed :)

Comment: btw array/list indexing is starting from 0

Comment: @Evilguy I  do not know enough about  the `data` array to assume that `count = 1` was  a mistake. Layoff a little.